# How can I use SAML for ASP.NET Core API authentication

Tags: angular, rest, .net-core, saml-2.0, sap-gateway

I want to apologise as I have absolutely no clue of SAML, but here is my (probably stupid) question:

In our corporate environment, we use SAML to authenticate users on our SAP Launchpad. I have a SPA on the Launchpad, which is thus secured by SAML, if my thoughts are right.

This application needs to authenticate to an external REST API that I have written myself. Now I want to secure the REST API using the same SAML IDP.

Is it possible to add the .NET application to the same SAML IDP and secure it this way?

My goal is to make the login on the REST API invisible for the user.

The picture below shows my aimed scenario. The left side of the picture does already exist, the right side does not.

[image: System Landscape]

Comment: Yes! You’ll need a library though

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! Do you know one that is suited for this use-case?